# hibernate mapping to versioned entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have entity that has a version. It has composite primary key where one part of it is id of an entity and other is version. I want to create many-to-one mapping to this entity, and I need to have the latest version on the many side of this mapping.

For example:

```
 @Entity
 @IdClass(VersionedId.class)
 class SomeVersionedComponent {
     private Long id;
     private long version;
     ...
 }

 @Entity
 class ManyMappingSide {
     private Long id;
     private SomeVersionedComponent component;

     @ManyToOne ///????
     public SomeVersionedComponent getComponent() {...}
     public void setComponent(SomeVersionedComponent component) {...}
 }
```

I do not need to save version information in ManyMapingSide, I just need to have only id, and when ManyMappingSide is loaded I want to have the latest version of SomeVersionedComponent.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to the versioning supported by [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers).  You might want to look at that and incorporate it into your design instead of trying to make your own versioning scheme.